# Applying clip filter to several sources

Tags: pipeline, paraview

I have several data source in Paraview, and clip all of them (with the Clip filter) to only the are of interest I need to see at this moment. It istedious to set the clip domain always three (or more) times. Is it somehow possible to share those parameters, or apply the same filter instance to multiple data sources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select all the data sources, then apply the **Group Datasets** filter. This will create a single data set (without actually duplicate the heavy data). Now you can just apply a single Clip filter.

You can alternatively use the **Links Manager**, accessible from *Tools | Manage Links* to set up property links between several Clip filters. This, however, had issues in some old versions. I'd suggest using 4.1.0 if you're going this route.

Comment: Great, I have 4.0.1 so I will try with Links Manager.